# Why does ElementById return null for a Sharepoint app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, css

I'm trying to get the an element's ID tag using JavaScript in order to manipulate the styles. The element is created by an app from the Office Store but I would like to change the look.

```
<div class="webPart_content">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="200" class="webPart_canvas floatLeft " height="150" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></canvas>
    <div class="webPart_desc">
        Your Profile<br>
        Strength Is<br>
        <span class="percent" id="completePercent">61%</span>
        <br>
        <a target="_parent" id="btnUpdate" class="button">Update</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added a snippet to the page with the following javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function ()
{
var x = document.getElementById("myChart");
x.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you try a few things to debug?:throw an alert(x) in there to see if it returns an object   
Try it via jQuery instead (Browser issue?)  
$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });  
Ensure there isn't another element with an id "myChart" on the same page somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If this is an App part, the content is inside an IFRAME. You'll first have to get the IFRAME then `myChart`

Something like this:

```
document.getElementById('iframeIDhere').contentWindow.document.getElementById('myChart')
```

Comment: But the ID of the iframe changes every time the page is refreshed or loaded.

Comment: Umh, tbh I'm not sure if there is an easy way if you don't have control over the app part, or if there is an object in page. But you could try getting from the src property if thats unique enough. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917325/how-do-i-select-an-iframe-by-the-src-attribute-using-jquery